# Using XGB or a Random Forest Model for Interaction Minion to later include in Logistic Regression Model

Tags: logistic, interaction, random-forest, feature-selection

I am currently developing a logistic regression model, I already have some expert based interactuion terms I will implement but I want to further figure out possible interactions I can implement in the Logistic Regression. Now I was thinking if it would make sense to fit a XGBoost/Random Forest model to my data with the restriction of a maximum depth of 2, and then I would go over all of my trees in the forest and look which variables are interacting. Do you have any idea if there are already some packages in Python which can deal with this kind of stuff?

Thanks a lot in advance and BR
Paul

Comment: In [his PyData talk](https://youtu.be/rQd5nzktKz0?si=bqX9ZaQZ05Pv_O38&t=650) Ben Fowler mentioned [xgbfir package](https://github.com/limexp/xgbfir) for identifying interactions within XGBoost models, although I haven't tried it myself. Also SHAP computes [interaction values](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/tree_based_models/Basic%20SHAP%20Interaction%20Value%20Example%20in%20XGBoost.html). The exact algorithms and assumptions/heuristics behind those two are of course different.

Answer (score 0):

A potential problem with this approach would be in assuming the interaction identified via RF is appropriate for the interactions in the logistic regression model.  Since Leo Breiman (Stats, U-C Berkeley) recommended using 5,000-10,000 trees for RF (i.e., "don't be stingy"), I wouldn't want to "look" through 5,000-10,000 trees for anything.  Moreover, the interaction between predictors in logistic will be preserved throughout all the partial derivative calculations in the score vector and Hessian matrix during Newton-Raphson iteration.  RF, however, is a derivative-free method essentially based on bootstrapping and using cutpoints (like CART), so it's a not a small jump to say what happens in RF regarding interaction can describe interaction in a logistic regression model.